# Bulk remove scheme/protocol/domain from internal referencing links

Tags: visual-studio-code, dreamweaver, batch-rename

I created a website years ago, but I don't have the original files, just what I was able download off the site. The website's internal links are all fully qualified (with domain name). Is there a way to remove the URL from all the links?

i.e. `http://drawingproject.frostartmuseum.org/events/` should be
`/events`

I'm using Dreamweaver and Visual Studio Code. I have a PC.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi there, welcome to stack overflow! This question has probably been answered in more general terms: you want to remove the *prefix* of all URL strings. The easiest thing to do might be to write a stand-alone program / utility script that simply looks for a certain URL (anything starting with your *prefix*) and a removes the prefix, anywhere in a given file.

Comment: Spelling.  Clarification. Removed irrelevant "I'm new" stuff.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This seemed to do the trick!